# Code Comment in directlua

Tags: luatex, lua, directlua

How can I add comments to my `directlua` code?

```
{\catcode`\%=12
\directlua{
function boxed (s)
 ??? Add a comment ???
 if not(boxedflag) then
  i=string.find(s,'^!!!')
  if(i==1) then
    boxedflag=true
    print('A' ..string.gsub(s,'^!!! (%a*) "(.*)"', '\string\\mybox{%1}{%2}['))
    return string.gsub(s,'^!!! (%a*) "(.*)"', '\string\\mybox{%1}{%2}{')
  else
    return s
  end
else
  i=string.find(s,'^XXX')
  if i==1 then
   print('C' .. s)
   return string.gsub(s,'^XXX','')
  else
    print('B' .. s)
    boxedflag=false
    return '}' .. s
  end
 end
end}
}
```

I want to add a comments in the code of the function boxed. I tried `-- comment`
and `\% comment` but both gave a error.

Any ideas how you can add comments in directlua functions?

Comment: Code in the argument to `\directlua` is read in with the normal TeX conventions *and* expansion. Better storing complex Lua code in a separate file and load it as a function.

Comment: The final `}` was not included in the code area. I suggest editing to fix that, in case anyone wants to try your code.

Answer (score 10):

Two suggestions:

- As @egreg has already noted in a comment, you could store your Lua code in an external file (typically, but not necessarily, with extension `.lua`), and load the code into Lua(La)TeX via a `\directlua{dofile(...)}` (or similar) directive. All native Lua syntax, including `--` to initiate comments, is allowed. If you need to output a `\` (backslash) character inside a string, you'll need to input `\\` since, as you probably know, `\` all by itself is Lua's escape character.
- For shorter pieces of Lua code, for which it's too much overhead to create external `.lua` files, you could load the [luacode](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/luacode) package and use either a `luacode` environment or a `luacode*` environment. In both environments, `--` is treated as the start of a comment. The main difference between the `luacode` and `luacode*` environments is that TeX macros are allowed in the former but not in the latter.

The `luacode` package also provides the nifty helper macros `\luastring`, `\luastringN`, and `\luastringO` for passing strings that may contain TeX-special characters and/or TeX macros. The three macros differ as follows: the argument of `\luastring` is expanded (in the TeX sense of the word) before being passed to Lua, that of `\luastringN` is not expanded at all, and that of `\luastringO` is expanded only once (and of the first token only).

Comment: thanks! i really appreciate your constructive feedback on my luacode since i'm fairly new to latex and luatex. Thanks a lot Mico.

Comment: Explanation: I use the luacode to parse a non latex syntax (Markdown Admonition Syntax) to Latex friendly styling. The print statements are just for testing purposes and debugging. I will remove them and improve the code according to your tipps. Thanks

Comment: @FabioSchmid - I decided to delete my cooments about the Lua code after I realized that that the code came from somebody else's answer to an earlier query of yours.

Answer (score 0):

This parsed. Whether it does what you want, is for you to decide:

```
\def\cmnt#1{} % ignores the argument
{\catcode`\%=12
\directlua{
function boxed (s)
\cmnt{Works for me.}
... the rest of your code
```