# Including a comment environment in a LuaTeX form letter implementation

Tags: luatex, letters, comments, forms

My OS is Debian GNU/Linux 10.2 (buster). TeX Live is a backport from unstable, version `2019.20190605.51237-3` (a snapshot of TeX Live 2019).

The code below is an LuaTeX form letter implementation. Without the `comment` environment lines, it compiles without problems. With the comment environment, it gives the following error. I'd like use a comment environment with this implementation of a form letter. How can I fix this?

```
LaTeX Warning: Writing or overwriting file `./formletter.lua'.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty
Excluding comment 'comment')

LaTeX Warning: Writing or overwriting file `./formletter_addresses.yaml'.

(./formletter.aux)
Foldmarks: yes
Head of first page
Foot of first page
Address (backaddress, addressee)
Location field: empty
Title: no
Subject: no
Excluding 'comment' comment.)
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
\par 
<*> formletter.tex

?
```

Code follows.

The `"\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}"` part wasn't my idea. I copied it from somewhere, though right now I'm not sure from where.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside=semi]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{luapackageloader}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{formletter.lua}
package.cpath="/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.3/?.so;/usr/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so;./?.so".\
.package.cpath
package.path="/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;/u\
sr/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;./?.lua"..package.path
local posix = require "posix"

local function loadyaml(config)
   local lyaml = require "lyaml"
   local s
   if posix.stat(config) ~= nil then
      local f = io.open(config)
      s = f:read("*all")
      f:close()
      return lyaml.load (s)
   end
end

local function formletter(config, text)
   t = loadyaml(config)
   for k,v in pairs(t) do
      -- texio.write_nl(v["Name"])
      -- texio.write_nl(v["MultiLineAddress"])
      tex.sprint(string.format([[\providecommand{\name}{%s}]], v["Name"]))                                                                         
      tex.sprint(string.format([[\renewcommand{\name}{%s}]], v["Name"]))                                                                           
      tex.sprint(string.format([[\providecommand{\multilineaddress}{%s}]], v["MultiLineAddress"]))                                                 
      tex.sprint(string.format([[\renewcommand{\multilineaddress}{%s}]], v["MultiLineAddress"]))                                                   
      tex.sprint(text)
   end
end

return {formletter=formletter}
\end{filecontents}
\directlua{formletter = require "formletter.lua"}
\NewDocumentCommand{\formletter}{m +m}
{
  \directlua{formletter.formletter("\luaescapestring{#1}","\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}")}
}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{formletter_addresses.yaml}
- Name: Name1
  MultiLineAddress: Address1
- Name: Name2
  MultiLineAddress: Address2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\formletter{formletter_addresses.yaml}
{% Begin formletter (\formletter second argument)                                                                                                  
  \begin{letter}{\name\\\multilineaddress}

    \opening{Dear \name}
    Hello
    \begin{quoting}
      Something quoted.
    \end{quoting}
    \closing{Yours Sincerely,}
    \begin{comment}
      A comment
    \end{comment}
  \end{letter}

}% End formletter                                                                                                                                  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are passing content from TeX to Lua just to pass it from Lua back to TeX?  Sounds like an [XY problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean) to me.

Comment: The actual problem is of course that tokenization as `#1` will eat the newlines.  You will have to change catcodes for that.

Comment: @HenriMenke I removed most of the context for simplicity. You folks want a MWE, remember? :-) I take it that the comment environment does something special, which is causing problems?

Comment: Yes, the `comment` environment reads its content as an argument and therefore has to look ahead for `\end{comment}`.  It also wants `\end{comment}` to be on a separate line.

Comment: comment is a verbatim like environment so will not work in the argument of another command. What are you actually trying to do? The solution here is simply to remove the comment environment but presumably you had some use case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, if it doesn't work, I guess I can't use it, then. There is no workaround? Yes, I wanted to use the comment environment. That was my use case.

Comment: @FaheemMitha there are always workarounds but only if you say what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought that the example shown was sufficient, but if you want more context, I'll have to rewrite the example. Should I ask another question, or change this one?

Comment: edit this one I guess as it has no answers that would be invalidated. The problem with it as it is, is that the most natural fix is simply to remove the comment environment, since it generates an error and does nothing if you stopped it making an error.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346676/code-comment-in-directlua maybe this?

Comment: @AFeldman No, I don't think that's the same issue. He wants to add comments to his Lua code, though it's directly included in the TeX file via `\directlua`. The general recommendation is to have Lua code in a separate file, like I do. And in that case, one can just use the usual Lua comment conventions.

Comment: @AFeldman BTW, if you're a lawyer as it says in your profile, do you use TeX much in your law work? Just curious. It seems to me that TeX can be quite useful in organizing and automating work in a legal context, though I've never heard of anyone doing this.

Comment: @AFeldman I've actually been trying to use LuaTeX for automating document generation in a legal context, with some amount of success. But it's been quite a lot of work. I'm not a professional lawyer, though.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I have used Latex in my legal pleadings for years. It has been awesome in helping me to make better pleadings.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I just saw your edit to this question but I still don't get what you are doing.  Why are passing the second argument to `\fromletter` to Lua at all?  You're not even doing anything with, you just pass it to `tex.sprint` to feed it back to TeX.  Just don't do that.  Problem solved.

Comment: Hi @HenriMenke. Perhaps I'm missing something (it would not be the first time), but I'm looping over the text, which contains examples of macros like `\name`, which have different values for each loop. If you think passing the second argument to Lua is unnecessary, perhaps you could provide an example of how to do it? Because it's not obvious to me.